# $p(A) = 0 \Rightarrow A$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial with a nonzero constant term, and if $A$ is a square matrix for which $p(A)=0$, then $A$ is invertible.

I have no idea how to even begin to show this, so any tips would be very helpful.

Comment: It's clearly true for $A$ a $1\times 1$ matrix, at least.

Comment: Do you know the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Comment: We have not gone over the Cayley-Hamilton theorem @Alex Kruckman

Comment: That's ok - you don't need it, as demonstrated by AdLibutum's nice answer.

Comment: @Alexkruckman The theorem of Hamilton--Cayley is quite tangential here!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose that
$$
c_0A^n+c_1A^{n-1}+\cdots+c_{n-1}A+c_nI=0.
$$
If $c_n\neq0$ we can transform the above equality into
$$
I=A(c^\prime_0A^{n-1}+\cdots+c^\prime_{n-2}A+c^\prime_{n-1}I)
$$
where $c^\prime_k=-c_k/c_n$. Then the expression inside the $(\ )$ visibly gives the inverse of $A$.

Comment: Importantly, that '$+c_n$' is meant as '$+c_nI$' when substituting a matrix into a polynomial.

Comment: I'm confused as to why the equality can be transformed into the I expression. @AdLibitum

Comment: Now you can see the identity matrix also in the first equality of the answer. Divide the equation by $c_n$ and put everything but the $I$ on the other side. Finally pull $A$ from this side.